# Adapt JSON to different target systems integrations

Tags: python, json, integration, jsonschema, jsonconvert

Our system outputs a standard key-val JSON but some of our customers have different receiving systems that require different JSON conversions.

We are sure this is a common integration issue that was probably handled many time before. Hopefully without writing a custom conversion code per customer.

Requested differences:

- Different structure (e.g. a JSON object to describe each key:val pair with additional data)
- Different key names (e.g. a GUID instead of text)
- Different value names (e.g. a GUID instead of text)

Comment: Unclear what you're looking for

Comment: @CharlesLandau an open source or method not to write specific code to change JSON formats between different systems.

Comment: Ok but how is the computer supposed to know what changes you want to make to the JSON if you don't write any code? Do you just want a tool that has a GUI and converts the JSON "under the hood"?